# Exhaustive studies of states of conscious and how we know what we know?

Tags: epistemology, reference-request

Have been hunting for a while: Is there a sort of ***compendium of epistemology*** out there? Not a *who's who* in epistemology per se, rather more a *what's what* that spans all schools of thought, cultures, religions, time-periods, and is as objective as possible considering the nature and scope of the subject, i.e., the author(s) try to avoid the assumption of any particular worldview?

Examples of "what's what" would of course cover all the epistemology 101 topics, e.g. Platonism, Kantianism, phenomenology, psychology, etc., but then also include (perhaps) more obscure and specific things such as the [hypnagogic state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia), dreams, altered consciousness, meditative, intuition, inspiration, imagination, etc. Or is this hopelessly too broad? (Please don't just down vote this if so - or at least tell me why :)

Answer (score 1):

One example of such a text is the Oxford Dictionary of Philosophy.  Although printed in a dictionary format, the entries are often remarkably detailed. Importantly, all philosophical terms used in each entry are annotated by cross-reference.

Major entries are typically one or two pages in length, though the cross-referencing used can expand this considerably.

Each of the major topics you have mentioned is featured - i.e., Kant, Plato, phenomenology, etc..  Of the additional subjects you mention, it includes entries for dreams, intuition, and imagination.  For example, the entry for imagination cross-references Coleridge, thought experiments, and images.

The small-print text covers a little over four-hundred pages, though that includes non-epistemological entries.  The price is modest in paperback form.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Oxford Handbook of Epistemology quite helpful. It does a great job at clearly defining what each view or topic in epistemology is, before diving into the problems, virtues, and arguments for and against each view. There is a ton of information in it (around 600 pages) and I have yet to finish it, but it is very readable and a great reference.

I checked the index and unfortunately Hypnagogia is not contained within the book bindings.

The titles of the chapters within are as follows

> I. Conditions and Analysis of Knowing
>
> II. The Sources of Knowledge
>
> III. A Priori Knowledge
>
> IV. The Sciences and Epistemology
>
> V.Conceptual Diversity in Epistomology
>
> skipping some here
>
> VII Internalism and Externalism
>
> X. Mind and Knowledge
>
> XI. Skepticism
>
> XV. Decision Theory and Epistomology
>
> XVII. Epistomology and Ethics

A total of 19 chapters, they say 20, but the last chapter is an extensive Bibliography.

```
ISBN 978-0-19-530170-0
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is *An Introduction to Western Philosophy* by Antony Flew.